# How do i order the numbers a user inputs?

Tags: python

I am basically wondering how i can store the users inputs and put them in order from least to greatest to help them find median mode or range.

```
from __future__ import division
amtnum = 0
sumofnums = 0

print "Hello, This program will help find the mean of as many numbers as you want."
useramtnum = input("How many numbers will you need to enter: ")#asks user to say how many numbers there are
while amtnum < useramtnum:         #Tells program that while the amount of numbers is less than the users input amt of numbers to run.
    amtnum = amtnum + 1         #Tells that each time program asks for number add one to amt of numbers
    entnum = (int(raw_input("Enter a number:"))) #Asks user for number
    sumofnums = entnum + sumofnums #Adds users number to all values

print "The amount of your numbers added up were:", sumofnums
print "The average/mean of your numbers were:", (sumofnums/useramtnum)
```

Answer (score 3):

put 'em in a list and sort it

```
mylist = []
while ...
    mylist.append(entnum)

mylist.sort()
print mylist
```

Comment: the problem is it doesn't save each entnum so it gives me 1 number as the sorted mylist

Answer (score 1):

Utilize the basic data structure called a list!

1. Before your while loop, create a list (aka array)

   `user_input_list = []`
2. After you get the individual number from the user in the while loop, add the input to the list (in the while loop)

   `user_input_list.append(entnum)`
3. After the while loop, sort the list (it will sort in place)

   `user_input_list.sort()`

Then the list has every input from the user in sorted order, least to greatest.

To access the last item in the list, use array accessors.

```
user_input_list[-1]
```

To access median, utilize the fact you can use the length of the list. Access the length(list)/2 item

```
user_input_list[int( len(user_input_list) / 2)] #int cast used to remove decimal points
```

Answer (score 0):

I am by no means a Python expert (as in, this is like my third python program), but I think it's generally easier to call functions, be it in Python or in any other language. It makes code more readable.

These are all basic math functions, so I don't feel I deprived you of knowledge by just writing them. I did, however, leave the `range` function for you to write. (Since `mylist` is sorted, I'm sure you can figure it out.)

This allows the user to continually enter numbers and have the mean, median, and mode spit back at them. It doesn't handle non-integer input.

```
from collections import Counter
from decimal import *

def getMode(l):
    data = Counter(l)
    mode = data.most_common(1)
    print "mode:", mode

def getMean(l):
    length = len(l)
    total = 0
    for x in l:
        total = total + x
    mean = Decimal(total) / Decimal(length)
    print "mean:", mean

def getMedian(l):
    median = 0
    length = len(l)
    if (length % 2 == 0):
        median = (l[length/2] + l[length/2 - 1])/2.0
    else:
        median = l[length/2]
    print "median:", median

mylist = []

print "Enter numbers to continually find the mean, median, and mode"

while True:
    number = int(raw_input("Enter a number:"))
    mylist.append(number)
    mylist.sort()
    getMean(mylist)
    getMedian(mylist)
    getMode(mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution to solve your problem :

- Use a list : [More on Lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Example :

```
numbers = []
while amount < counter:
    ...
    numbers.append(num)
print sorted(numbers)
```

You can take a look at modification of your code below.

```
numbers = []

print "Hello, This program will help find the \
       mean of as many numbers as you want."

while True:
    try:
        counter = input("How many numbers will you need to enter: ") 
    except:
        print "You haven't entered a number."
    else:
    break

amount = 0
while amount < counter:
    try:
        num = input("Enter a number: ")
    except:
        print "You haven't entered a number."
    else:
        amount += 1
    numbers.append(num)

print "The amount of your numbers added up were:", (sum(numbers))
print "The average/mean of your numbers were:",  ( (sum(numbers)) / counter)
print "My list not in order:", numbers
print "My list in order:", sorted(numbers)
```